# Join two files together (AWK)

Tags: perl, awk, merge

I have one problem. I would like to merge two files together. Where:

**File 1:**

```
 chr**1  10000**   rs200132 A  C  100.000
 chr**2  20000**   rs5000   C  G   80.000
```

**File 2:**

```
 rs200132  **1:10000**  A   800   200  Nmf 
 rs210111  **1:10000**  G   200   800  VFC 
 rs310000  **1:10000**  C   100   500  tff
 rs50001   **2:20000**  T   500   100  jpp
 rs60000   **2:20000**  A   1000   10  jkl
```

**Output:**

```
 chr**1  10000**  rs200132  A  A  C   800   200  Nmf
 chr**1  10000**  rs210111  G  A  C   200   800  VFC
 chr**1  10000**  rs310000  C  A  C   100   500  tff
 chr**2  20000**  rs50001   T  C  G   500   100  jpp
 chr**2  20000**  rs60000   A  C  G   1000   10  jkl
```

Than, from the first file are the marks number after "chr" and in the second column the number. The same marks are in the second file, but there is in second column like 1:10000. I would like to join this two file but for the first file will be much more joined rows (f.e.: for the first row from the first file will be three rows from the second file.)
Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far? StackOverflow users are happy to help, but doing your homework may be more difficult :)

Comment: Are the stars part of the real file data?

Comment: No stars are not of the real file data..

Comment: And I create a perl code, but it doesnt work like I want...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this `awk`,

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1;b[$2]=$4" "$5;next} {sub(/.*:/,"",$2); $3=$1" "$3" "b[$2]; $1=a[$2];}1' file1 file2
```

**Test:**

```
sat:~# awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1;b[$2]=$4" "$5;next} {sub(/.*:/,"",$2); $3=$1" "$3" "b[$2]; $1=a[$2];}1' file1 file2
chr**1 10000** rs200132 A A C 800 200 Nmf
chr**1 10000** rs210111 G A C 200 800 VFC
chr**1 10000** rs310000 C A C 100 500 tff
chr**2 20000** rs50001 T C G 500 100 jpp
chr**2 20000** rs60000 A C G 1000 10 jkl
```

Answer (score 4):

```
perl -lane'
  BEGIN{ $x=pop; %h = map{ $_->[1] => $_ } map [split], <>; @ARGV=$x }
  $F[1] =~ s/.+?://;
  $t = $h{$F[1]};
  print join " ", @$t[0,1], @F[0,2], @$t[3,4], @F[3..5];
' file1 file2
```

output

```
chr**1 10000** rs200132 A A C 800 200 Nmf
chr**1 10000** rs210111 G A C 200 800 VFC
chr**1 10000** rs310000 C A C 100 500 tff
chr**2 20000** rs50001 T C G 500 100 jpp
chr**2 20000** rs60000 A C G 1000 10 jkl
```

Comment: @JS웃 `%h` is hash of arrays where keys are second column of file1. You can check it with `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \%h`. There are few books worth reading if you want to learn perl, although they are not dedicated as much to command line usage.

Comment: @JS웃 [Effective Perl Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_Perl_Programming) I'd say it's about idiomatic/zen perl (there is also 2nd edition of the book, but didn't have chance to look at it)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way using Perl:

```
perl -lane '
    if (@ARGV) {
        ($x = $F[0]) =~ s/[^\d]*//;
        $h{$x}{$F[1]} = [ @F[0,1,3,4] ]
    }
    else {
        @t = split(":", $F[1]);
        $r = $h{$t[0]}{$t[1]};
        print join(" ", @$r[0,1], @F[0,2], @$r[2,3], @F[3..5])
    }
' file1 file2 | column -t
```

Results:

```
chr1  10000  rs200132  A  A  C  800   200  Nmf
chr1  10000  rs210111  G  A  C  200   800  VFC
chr1  10000  rs310000  C  A  C  100   500  tff
chr2  20000  rs50001   T  C  G  500   100  jpp
chr2  20000  rs60000   A  C  G  1000  10   jkl
```